# Generating unique number combinations, with each number occuring same amount

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to make a tournament schedular in which a certain amount of unique matches is created (For which I made the code below) but, I would like to have it so that each team has an equal amount of matches

```
NumberOfTeams = 21;
NumberOfFields = 7;
NumberOfRounds = 10;

TeamList = Table[i, {i, NumberOfTeams}];
Games = Permutations[TeamList, {2}];

ListPossibleGames = DeleteDuplicates[Map[Sort, Games]]
RandomGames =RandomSample[ListPossibleGames,NumberOfFields*NumberOfRounds]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's declare a variable `game`, which can be indexed like `g[i, j]`.

- It can be `0` or `1`.
- If `game[i, j]` is 1, then there is a game to be played between team `i` and `j`. Similarly, if `game[i, j]` is 0, then there is no game to be played between team `i` and `j`.

Now, we can define constraints

- Since the number of matches played by every team is same, we get, 
  $$\sum_{j = 1}^{n} \text{game}[1, j] = \sum_{j = 1}^{n} \text{game}[2, j] = \sum_{j = 1}^{n} \text{game}[3, j]...$$
- No self game, so, $\text{game[i, i]} = 0$
- $\text{game}[i,j] = \text{game}[j, i]$
- $0<=\text{game}[i,j] <= 1$

**Code**

```
SetAttributes[game, Orderless]
genSum[i_, n_] := Total[game[i, #] & /@ Range[n]] /. game[i, i] -> 0;
vars[n_] := game @@@ Subsets[Range[n], {2}];

genEqns[teams_, matches_] := {Equal @@ (genSum[#, teams] & /@ Range[teams]), 
    Total[vars[teams]] == matches, Thread[0 <= vars[teams] <= 1]} // Flatten;

grid[n_, sol_] := 
     Grid[(Prepend[
          Join[{#} & /@ Range[n], Table[game[i, j], {i, n}, {j, n}], 
           2], {"Teams", Sequence @@ Range[n]}] /. sol) /. 
       game[i_, i_] :> X,
      Dividers -> {{False, True}, {False, True}}, ItemSize -> All, 
      Spacings -> 2, Dividers -> {2 -> Red, 2 -> Red}]
```

Finally, solving the equations (you can also use [`FindInstance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html) to get a solution.)

```
tournament[teams_, matches_] := Solve[genEqns[teams, matches], vars[teams], Integers]
```

**Test**

Let's start with smaller numbers. Consider, number of teams to be `4` and total matches to be `4`.

```
sols = tournament[4, 4]
```

> {{game[1, 2] -> 0, game[1, 3] -> 1, game[1, 4] -> 1, game[2, 3] -> 1, 
>     game[2, 4] -> 1, game[3, 4] -> 0}, {game[1, 2] -> 1, 
>     game[1, 3] -> 0, game[1, 4] -> 1, game[2, 3] -> 1, game[2, 4] -> 0, 
>     game[3, 4] -> 1}, {game[1, 2] -> 1, game[1, 3] -> 1, 
>     game[1, 4] -> 0, game[2, 3] -> 0, game[2, 4] -> 1, game[3, 4] -> 1}}

We get three solutions. Lets display the first solution in grid form.

```
grid[4, sols[[1]]]
```

> [image]

Now, for teams of `21` and matches of `70`, there are no solutions. The closest you can get is when matches is `63`. You get solutions only when matches is a multiple of `21` until `210` ($21 C_2$).

```
sols = tournament[21, 63];
grid[21, sols[[1]]]
```

> [image]

Note: Because of my system limitations, I have used [`FindInstance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html) to display one  solution.

Hope this helps.